# Copying list of objects to list objects of inherited type having additional properties

Tags: c#, casting, .net

I  have got a List1 of objects of type

```
public class ClassName1
{

    public ClassName1()
    {
    }

    public short Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

}
```

and an empty List2 for objects of type

```
public class ClassName2: ClassName1
{
    public double Prop3;
}
```

I would like to copy the contents of List1 to List2 by doing

```
IList<ClassName2> List2 = List1.Cast<ClassName2>().ToList();
```

But I get:

> 'InvalidCastException was unhandled. Unable to cast object of type 'Namespace.ClassName1' to type 'Namespace.ClassName2'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ClassName2 inherites from ClassName1, not the other way around, so you can only cast from 2 to 1

Comment: You cannot cast a parent to a child, only vice-versa.  Not every animal is a dog but every dog is an animal. Or if the parent is actually a "hidden" child: `Animal a = new Dog()`

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you cannot. Every `ClassName2` is a `ClassName1`, but not every `ClassName1` is a `ClassName2`. That means you can assign a `ClassName2` to a `ClassName1` variable but you can not assign a `ClassName1` to a `ClassName2` variable. And since you cannot do it for a single variable, you cannot do it for a list, contravariant or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this instead:

```
IList<ClassName2> List2 = l1.Select(x => new ClassName2 { Prop1 = x.Prop1, Prop2 = x.Prop2 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The cast is impossible because you cannot cast a parent to a child, but you can always do it manually:

```
foreach(var item in list1)
{
   List2.Add(new ClassName2{Prop1 = item.Prop1, Prop2 = item.Prop2, Prop3 = 0})
}
```